Trying to build a buck converter with LM2576 Adjustable
I'm trying to build 12V buck converter based on this schematic

this is what I did


Is this already good enough, or does it need some more change?
this is my first trying to build something like this and any help/suggestion would be much appreciated.

If you are going to actually use the hand-soldered prefboard, you should try to make a layout where the distance between the GND pin and the diode + caps is minimized. Then connect that one directly to the PCB GND connection. Then worry about the rest. Even after that, I suspect that this will be godawful noisy and cause EMC problems. You can't really use these regulators without 4 layer SMD stackup on a real PCB.

@Lundin I disagree on needing a 4-layer PCB.

@EdinFifić Any actual arguments why? Many of the simple switcher parts have poor EMC characteristics even with a perfect layout on 4 layer boards. I've used these families for some 15 years until eventually banning them from new projects - the parts are simply too bad. But then I work with industrial/automotive/military electronics - if you are doing cheap consumer stuff they might work out ok.

@Lundin I agree with everything you said in your last comment, I just didn't agree that he would need a 4-layer PCB for his purposes. Not even the manufacturer recommends a multi-layer PC in their datasheet for this IC, and in their Application Note referenced in the datasheet they briefly mention some important considerations if a multi-layer PCB is used. That document is here: https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/SNVA054  I am also aware of the bad EMI from many switchers, had issues with neighbors due to a switcher interfering with their TV reception, and a switching lab PS causes noise on my scope.

@Lundin Which switcher families do you recommend for a reduced EMI?

@EdinFifić I use pretty much exclusively AD parts (former LT) these days. What family to use depends on the project requirements, naturally. They actually have tech support too, so one can outline the requirements for an engineer and get help with picking the best part.

Have you tested its performance, does it behave as it should?
You have not shown a PROBLEM that needs to be solved, you are merely asking if the circuit you have built is OK, and we can't tell you for sure without you actually measuring its performance.
Some things can't be seen from pictures, but what I can see is that you haven't really used the "star-connection-grounding" as I would call it.
Namely, each of the components in the schematic (Cin, D1, Cout) should have their own separate path to one common ground point in order to ensure no ground loop (elevated ground voltages) problems.
Additionally, switching regulators and their critical supporting components should have PCB paths as short as possible.

Thanks for the tips. As for the problem, I tried testing it with a power supply, but it keeps switching to CC mode, so I can’t increase the voltage(only the current).

@MufattehM THAT info and all other relevant details should have been included in your question, along with a screenshot of your measurements like oscilloscope or DMM. What were you R1 and R2 values?

R1 = 1k ; R2 = 8.75k . As for the measurement, I didn’t take a picture, but the voltage stays stuck at around 1 volt, and I’m only able to increase the current

@MufattehM That should give you 12V on the output. What is the load, the input voltage, and have you tested other components to see if they are not faulty?
